# What is the Bone Amulet for?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've found a few Bone Amulets around Grimrock. I think I found them after killing the undead skeletons, but I'm not 100% sure. They seems to have no stats, positive or negative, and only a short description, reading *A primitive amulet made out of bones that are bound together with string*. So what are they for?

Is there any use for them or are they just dead weight? (hah, pun)
Am I missing something and being totally bone-headed?
I thought maybe they are in fact completely useless, but I can't get that into my thick skull.
Will I find out to-*marrow*?

Comment: there is a use for it later IIRC, any more information is a spoiler.

Comment: @ewanm89 We shouldn't avoid giving good answers because they contain spoilers. The entire point of this site is to answer people's questions. If that requires spoilers, so be it.

Comment: As an added note, if you are really keen on hiding the spoilers, you can still answer the question but wrap spoilery bits in the spoiler tag, which is `>!`

Comment: no, that's what spoiler tags are for (you might want to use them), but I made a comment, not gave a full answer.

Comment: I'd also point out Legend of Grimrock is all about its puzzles, so all my comment does is tell him it's worth still carrying or at least knowing where it is.

Comment: @ewanm89 Your comment was fair, but I was worried it discouraged the other answer from providing more detail. My thought is that if people are specifically looking for at a question asking how the bone amulet is used, they've probably decided they're okay with being spoiled on how it's used! Anyway, we can have the best of both worlds with a spoiler tag. Win-win!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iron door on Level 9 has the following riddle:

> The clue is
>  Made from the dead
>  Guillotined man
>  does not
>   need me

The bone amulet is the answer to the riddle, which you solve by placing it in the alcove next to the door.

Comment: This should definitively have a spoiler warning at the very least.

Answer (score 6):

It is used to unlock a door much much later in the game.

Answer (score 2):

As an additional note, there's two bone amulets available in the game (as far as I can tell), but you only need one of them. So if you find both, there's no need to keep the spare.